Partitioning a $54-63-63$ Triangle into 4 Isosceles Triangles Construction
Original Problem: Find five different methods to cut up an isosceles triangle with angles $54-63-63$ into four smaller isosceles triangles.
My Problem:
I have been going through a Chinese mathematics online course, and the maths teacher had glossed over how to construct the methods. I had managed to figure out most of them, but I am a little bit confused over one method, which divides the triangle into isosceles triangles of base angles $54^\circ, 58.5^\circ, 63^\circ$ and $67.5^\circ$ (all numbers mean degrees). A diagram of this is shown below.

I let the top vertex of the large isosceles triangle be $A$, the bottom left be $B$ and the bottom right be $C$. The construction I have attempted is as follows:
Get any two points $D'$ on $BC$ and $F'$ on $AC$ such that $CD'=CF'$. Construct the perpendicular through $C$ of $D'F'$, and let this intersect $AB$ at point $E$. Then, let there be a point on $AC$ called $F$ such that $AE=EF$ and let there be a point $D$ on $BC$ such that $DE=EF$. However, I cannot prove that triangles $BED$ and $CDF$ are isosceles, and I also cannot prove that the base angle of $DEF$ is $67.5^\circ$.
Could anyone please provide a construction to partition the triangle like above? (Also, if possible, don't use trigonometry too much; a solution with trigonometry is fine, but it will be better without if possible.) Thank you!

You can technically do it, since all angles are multiples of $1.5$ degrees, which is $\frac{\pi}{120} = \frac{2\pi}{2^4\cdot3\cdot5}$, and therefore the cosine and sine of these angles are constructible numbers. But the cosine of $1.5$ degrees looks like a pretty gnarly expression, and I'm not sure it would be very enlightening.

I misunderstood the question; I thought you had to construct everything, including the large triangle. Apparently, the large triangle is given?

There's nothing special about the given angles. Here's a construction that works for any isosceles $\triangle ABC$ with vertex $A$.


Let the angle bisector at $C$ meet the opposite leg at $P$.
Let $Q$ be the reflection of $A$ in the perpendicular from $P$ to leg $\overline{AC}$. Thus $\overline{PA}\cong\overline{PQ}$ and $\angle A=\angle AQP$.
Let $R$ be the reflection of $Q$ in line $CP$; note that $R$ necessarily lies on base $\overline{BC}$. In the resulting kite $\square CQPR$, we have $\overline{CQ}\cong\overline{CR}$, $\overline{PQ}\cong\overline{PR}$. Moreover, we deduce that $\angle BRP\cong\angle PQA\cong\angle A$, making $\triangle RPB$ isosceles (similar to $\triangle ABC$) with vertex $R$; hence $\overline{RB}\cong\overline{RP}$.

Consequently, $\triangle PQR$ is the central triangle of the partition in question.

May I ask why $R$ necessarily lies on $\overline{BC}$? Thank you!

@CheeseCake: "May I ask why $R$ necessarily lies on $\overline{BC}$?" Sure! ... Since $R$ (wherever it is) is defined to be the reflection of $Q$ in $CP$, we have that $\angle QCP\cong\angle RCP$. But $\angle QCP=\frac12\angle C$ (because $CP$ was constructed as the angle bisector at $C$), so that $\angle RCP=\frac12\angle C$, as well, which places $R$ on $BC$. ... Does that help?

Thank you for your help!
